# Opencl select method with scalar argument

Tags: opencl

I have the following line of code, where I want each component of a4 to equal the corresponding component of c4 if scalar is non zero, otherwise set it to the corresponding component of b4:

```
 uint4 a4 =       select(b4,   c4,   (uint4)(scalar != 0));
```

But, reading the select docs, it looks like MSB must be set for the c4 component to be chosen.

Is the above line correct? I have a feeling it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to adjust the third argument to:
     (uint4)scalar != 0

and it will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nasty little one. The value of truth for a scalar doesn't match the value of truth for a vector. It's a consequence of trying to efficiently support altivec/SSE-style masking on comparison. It's a known but not widely publicised quirk of OpenCL.

Comment: Yeah, this bit me for a while. And it makes it a bit dangerous to simply port scalar code to vector code.