# do not understand result of opencl select statement

Tags: opencl

I have a simple kernel in OpenCL that has the following structure:

```c
kernel void simple_select(global double *input, global double *output) {
  size_t i = get_global_id(0);
  printf("input %d\n", (int)(input[i] != 0.0));
  output[i] = select((float)0.0, (float)1.0, (int)(input[i] != 0.0));
  //output[i] = select((float)0.0, (float)1.0, 1);
}
```

Equivalently this can be:

```c
kernel void simple_select(global double *input, global double *output) {
  size_t i = get_global_id(0);
  printf("input %d\n", (int)(input[i] != 0.0));
  output[i] = input[i] != 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
  //output[i] = 1 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}
```

When I print to the command line, I see:

```
input 1
input 1
input 1
```

But the output array has all `0.0`.  However, if I uncomment the last line of the kernel and comment out the second-to-last-line (meaning if I use the scalar `1` in the select statement) then it works as expected and the output array has all `1.0`. So what is the difference between these two lines that leads to two different results?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895158/opencl-select-method-with-scalar-argument)

It's a quirk in OpenCL. The problem is that true/false values for scalars are 1/0 (like printf has shown you), but true/false values for vectors are -1/0 - and this is also what select() expects in last argument (more precisely, it expects MSB set which means any negative integer).

Though i think the ternary operator on scalars *should* still work as expected, if it doesn't i would consider it a bug.